# Why does the compiler say I can't insert an Item into a std::set<Item>?

Tags: c++, stl, insert, set, operator-keyword

I have a class called "Item" and i'm trying to insert an item to a set of items.

```
std::set<Item>::iterator it;
_items.insert(it, newItem);
```

but it gives me this weird error

```
Error   1   error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Item' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Even though I did implement this operator.

```
bool Item::operator<(Item& other)
{
    return _serialNumber < other._serialNumber;
}
```

I don't see why I need this operator in this function.

Does somebody know what the problem is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The hint was in the error: 'const Item', your operator should take other by const ref. (You should probably make the operator const as well)

Comment: Implement bool Item::operator<(const Item& other)

Comment: Also, your `it` iterator is not referencing anything, but you use it in the `insert` call.

Comment: Thanks but now it crashes :(

Comment: @AlonPe'er That would be an entirely different problem (one that is likely covered by Paul's comment). Suggest you read up on [**`std::set`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). **And don't ever change the fundamental context of a posted question!** You just made all answers and comments already posted utterly meaningless in the context of the now-posted text. If there is a different problem, post a new question.

Comment: @WhozCraig Agreed. Rolled back to your version.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know it was that horrible...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie what do you mean?

Comment: @AlonPe'er - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert  The functions that have iterators as the first argument are either hint, or an iterator that points to where you want to insert.  Your iterator is just declared, and then...nothing.  It is just sitting there waiting to have a good value assigned to it.  It is akin to declaring an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 4):

You should change the definition to :-

```
bool Item::operator<( const Item& other)  const
                      ^^^^^               ^^^^^
{
    return _serialNumber < other._serialNumber;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but now it crashes... :(

Comment: Time to debug it and raise another question in case issue persists :)

Answer (score 0):

> *"I don't see why I need this operator in this function."*

That's because you need to ensure, this operator function being called on *rvalue* instances of the `Item` class. That's a [**requirement**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) of `std::set` (and other container classes, where `Item` should be used as key).